# Minimize Dice Rolls in a game

Tags: probability-theory, optimization, game-theory, simulation

Theoretically, if I am rolling two fair 6 sided die and I want to minimize the number of times I have to roll them... for any outcome/payoff I want, how would I minimize the objective function of min(rolls)?

For instance, if I wish to receive payoff for rolling an 8, how would I state a mathematical expression for min(rolls) for a Payoff = 8?

Comment: Sorry, do you want to find the expected number of rolls until you get an 8?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, I meant to clarify that

Answer (score 1):

First, given that we roll two dice, the probability that we get an $8$ is $\frac{5}{36}$.  A simple counting argument shows this (the only pairs of dice that add to $8$ are $(2,6),(3,5),(4,4),(5,3),(6,2)$.  There are $5$ of these.  The total number of combinations of dice rolls is $6\times 6 = 36$. So, $5/36$).  So, let $p = 5/36$.

Now, the [Geometric Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) gives the probability that you need $k$ bernoulli trials to get 1 success.  Rolling an 8 with two dice is Bernoulli with $p = 5/36$, so if we let $X\sim\text{Geom}(5/36)$, we just want to find $E[X]$.  The mean of the Geometric is:
$$E[X] = \frac{1}{p} = \frac{36}{5} = 7.2$$

To find this generically, first find the probability of rolling whatever value with $2$ dice [(these are easy to find)](http://gwydir.demon.co.uk/jo/probability/calcdice.htm#sum), and then the expected number of rolls to get that number will be $1/p$.

Comment: Thanks Mark! How would I minimize the variance of the number of rolls in order to hold a E[x] = 7.2???

Comment: I'm unsure what you're asking (I'm familiar with probability, not optimization/game theory).  The variance of the geometric distribution is $(1-p)/p^2$.  So, If we have that $E[X] = k$ for some $k$, then $V[X] = k^2 -k$.  For the case where $E[X] = 7.2$, we get that $V[X] = 44.64$.

Comment: I see. I'm following you though my probability is rudimentary. I am trying to optimize a game where I simulate a player rolling 2 die. I want a payoff equal to the sum(die1,die2). Thus, if I roll 8, my payoff is = $8. But I want to achieve this with as few rolls as possible. In other words, min(rolls) to acheive 8. I understand the random component. And I understand the optimization strategy is not simple. Can you think of a basic optimization algorithm or strategy for this because I am stumped?

Comment: What parameters can you change?

Comment: It's a broad question that is intended to be left open ended. Ideally, minimize rolls of a dice to win some game of 2 dice. That's all I know. I'm not looking for someone to give me the answer; I just need to talk through it but everyone I talk to is not sure. It's ultimately a simulated game in MATLAB but it's more mathematical than comp sci

Comment: How do we minimize it though? To minimize a function, you have to do it with respect to some parameter. If you're assuming 2 fair 6 sided dice, I see no parameters. Things you could try changing are the fairness of the dice, the number of them, or the number of sides. Changing them in a way that'd decrease variance seems slightly contrived though (like making them biased towards 3 4 5 might keep the same mean if you do it right, and should decrease variance). It'd also make all the calculations more difficult by a decent amount.

Comment: I understand the conundrum. Similar in spirit to your examples, I am thinking of theoretical possibilities. The only way the roll could be optimized, assuming we keep the die "fair" every roll, is to assign weights or ranks.